AppRouter Next.js 15 layout hydration error
I have a simple app, using Next.js 15, using AppRouter.
I keep getting the following error:

Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the
client. As a result this tree will be regenerated on the client. This
can happen if a SSR-ed Client Component used

My layout.tsx looks like:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import Layout from "../components/shared/Layout";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "My awesome app",
  description: "some description here",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body style={{ minHeight: "100%", margin: 0 }}>
        <Layout>{children}</Layout>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The Layout.tsx is like:
"use client";
import { Box, Grid, styled } from "@mui/material";
import { SomeOtherStyledComponent, AndAThirdSyledComponent } from "@components/shared";

const SomeStyledComponent = sytled(Box)(() => ({
    // some style here
}));

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <SomeStyledComponent/>
      <Grid>
        <SomeOtherStyledComponent/>
        <AndAThirdSyledComponent>
          {children}
        </AndAThirdSyledComponent>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Layout;

Any help is much appreciated.

Just missing out MUI - Next.js integration:
https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/nextjs/#app-router
